# Problem with a NSString that equals to (null)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have an UIViewController named MainViewController
I have another UIViewController named LeftSharingViewController;

I would like to get and use the NSString from MainViewController in my LeftSharingViewController

I have a problem, I always get (null) instead of the NSString wanted value.

Here's my code and how does the NSString get it's value
MainViewController:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
     leftWebViewString = [NSString stringWithString:leftWebView.request.URL.absoluteString];
}
```

LeftSharingViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@class MainViewController;
@interface LeftSharingViewController : UIViewController         <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {
MainViewController *mainViewController;
NSString *leftWebViewUrl;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MainViewController *mainViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *leftWebViewUrl;
@end
```

LeftSharingViewController.m:

```
#import "LeftSharingViewController.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation LeftSharingViewController
@synthesize mainViewController;
@synthesize leftWebViewUrl;
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
self.leftWebViewUrl = self.mainViewController.leftWebViewString;
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Compose Mail
-(void)displayComposerSheet 
{
MFMailComposeViewController *mailPicker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailPicker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[mailPicker setSubject:@"Check Out This Website!"];
[mailPicker setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Take a look at this site:%@", leftWebViewUrl] isHTML:YES];

mailPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:mailPicker animated:YES];
[mailPicker release];

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked to make sure `leftWebViewString` is getting set correctly? That's the most likely source of (null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `MainViewController`, you are never retaining the `NSString` you create. You are using `stringWithString:`, which returns an autoreleased object.

You should either retain it, or (easier) change your code to use your accessor, which already retains, like this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    self.leftWebViewString = [NSString stringWithString:leftWebView.request.URL.absoluteString];
}
```

As a side note, if you are navigating from `MainViewController` to `LeftSharingViewController`, instead of "pulling" the data in `LeftSharingViewController` from `MainViewController`, I would do it the other way around:
In `MainViewController`, before displaying the view of `LeftSharingViewController`, I'd set the required properties.

Comment: Hi,
First thanks for answering me
I did what you wrote but I still get (null)
When you saying "retaining the NSString" do you me for this:

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *leftWebViewString;

?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure he means this: `leftWebViewString = [[NSString stringWithString:leftWebView.request.URL.absoluteString] retain];`  If you don't use `self.leftWebViewString` (which is a short-cut for `[self setLeftWebViewString: ]`) then the property won't retain it.

Comment: @Stephen Furlani: that's what I meant, yes.

Comment: Technically you should get `nil.`

Try `retain` ing it one more time.

Comment: NADA

Here's my updated code:

NSString *leftWebViewString;
@propert (nonatomic, retain) NSString *leftWebViewString;

leftWebViewString = [[NSString stringWithString:leftWebView.request.URL.absoluteString] retain];

Comment: Maybe the problem is here, in this code of the LeftSharingViewController:

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 self.leftWebViewUrl = self.mainViewController.leftWebViewString;
}